# Github workflows deploy multiple Terraform environments

Tags: terraform, github-actions

I have the following terraform scripts structure

```
environments
  |- dev
  |- staging
modules
```

Each environment has its own state stored in S3 and they create resources from the `modules` directory.
How can I deploy all terraform environments at once by using GitHub Workflows without having to duplicate the `init, plan, apply` steps for each env directory?

This is my current `yml` file for deploying the `dev` environment:

```
name: Terraform Deployment after push
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: write

env:
  AWS_REGION: us-east-1

jobs:
  merged:
    name: deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
        with:
          terraform_version: 1.2.6

      - name: Run terraform fmt check
        id: fmt
        run: terraform fmt -check -diff -recursive

      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}
          role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.ROLE }}
          role-session-name: InfraDeployOnMerge

      - name: Initialize Terraform
        id: init
        run: |
          cd environments/dev
          rm -rf .terraform.*
          terraform init -input=false

      - name: Terraform Validate
        id: validate
        run: terraform validate -no-color

      - name: Terraform Plan
        id: plan
        run: |
          cd environments/dev
          terraform plan -var="aws_region=${{ env.AWS_REGION }}" -var="aws_profile=" -input=false -no-color -out=tfplan \
          && terraform show -no-color tfplan
        continue-on-error: true

      - name: Apply Terraform
        if: steps.plan.outcome == 'success'
        id: apply
        continue-on-error: true
        run: |
          cd environments/dev
          terraform apply -input=false -no-color \
          tfplan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [github matrix syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs) to define multiple environments and use it to `cd` to respective folder and apply.

Or if possible adapt [terragrunt](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/) which makes your life easier to deploy to multiple accounts and environments.